Converting from an Int to a hex, and then saving to byte.. splitting the value
I am driving a stepper motor and you have to pass an array of bytes to control it.
One of the issues I have (newbie) is you have to pass the hex as two byte values...
For example if I want to set the speed to be 1200rpm, then you convert the 1200 to hex which is 04B0 and then you set two of the bytes.. one with 04 and the other with B0.. you can see here that as 0x04 and then 0xB0
MBData7 = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x06, 0x62, 0x03, 0x04, 0xB0, 0x66, 0xE8 };
Some speeds such as 100 are hex 64, it would be sent with the byte being 00 and the next byte as 64 so it would be
MBData7 = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x06, 0x62, 0x03, 0x00, 0x64, 0x66, 0xE8 };
What would be the best way that I could take an integer value, max would be 3500 and the min would be 60 and be able to generate the two byte value needed so I can pass them into the byte array as required....
Thanks

If you divide the number by 256 and capture the remainder, you will have the two required values. The dividend is the first byte, and the remainder is the second. In terms of sending the items to your device, all the device expects is a set of 8-bit values. The only time you need them "converted" to hex (although there is no such conversion) is when you display them for us poor humans to read.

Bytes store values between 0 and 255. Two digit hex values have the same range. Therefore, the hexadecimal representation is often used to represent bytes values. However, when converting an integer (no matter in which base) to bytes, what you really need is to convert it to base 256. An intermediate step into a hex representation is not required.
Algorithm (pseudo-code):
uint n = <value to be converted>; // or ushort or ulong.
byte[] bytes = new byte[<expected size>]; // Assuming array is initialized with 0s.
int i = <expected size>;
while (n > 0) {
   byte b = (byte)(n modulo 256);
   bytes[--i] = b;
   n = n / 256; // integer division
}


The Op says: "the min would be 60"

I mean, you can just make n unsigned, instead of having Assuming n >= 0. Then there's no precondition necessary, it just always works.

Here's some code that does what you want.
// A function to convert a speed value to a command byte array
public byte[] GetCommandArray(ushort speed) {
    // limit the input to the desired range
    var x = (ushort)(speed > 3500 ? 3500 : speed < 60 ? 60 : speed);
    // define the output template
    byte[] cmd = [0x01, 0x06, 0x62, 0x03, 0, 0, 0x66, 0xe8];
    // split the short into two bytes, and insert into the template
    cmd[4] = (byte)((x >> 8) & 0xff);
    cmd[5] = (byte)(x & 0xff);
    return cmd;
}

// define a function to format a byte array as a string, just to check operation
public string dump(byte[] ba) => String.Join(" ",ba.Select(b=>$"0x{b:X2}").ToArray());

// use on two examples
ushort speed= 1200;
Console.WriteLine($"speed: {speed} => Command data: {dump(GetCommandArray(speed))}");

speed = 100;
Console.WriteLine($"speed: {speed} => Command data: {dump(GetCommandArray(speed))}");

Outputs:
speed: 1200 => Command data: 0x01 0x06 0x62 0x03 0x04 0xB0 0x66 0xE8
speed: 100 => Command data: 0x01 0x06 0x62 0x03 0x00 0x64 0x66 0xE8

